# spring integration xpath namespace issue

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to use an an xpath expression, in order to read requestId field in the xml file given below. however, this expression results in no matches. When I try to enclose the field names with single quotes, it results in a compilation error.  I even tried using local-name, instead of name, in the xpath expression. I need to be able to get the value of requestId field as shown.

```
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="file" mode="APPEND" charset="UTF-8"
    directory="C:\\Users\\dvenkat1\\Desktop\\test" 
    auto-create-directory="true"  filename-generator-expression="#xpath(payload, '/*[name()=Envelope]/*[name()=Body]/*[name()=processArchiveRequest]/*[name()=fulfillmentRequest]/*[name()=requestHeader]/*[name()=requestID]/text()')" />
```

---

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"        xmlns:sch="http://...schema">
     <soap:Header/>
     <soap:Body>
     <sch:processArchiveRequest>
          <sch:fulfillmentRequest>
              <sch:requestHeader>
                 <sch:requestID>Samplereq</sch:requestID>
             ............
```

Another option would be, is to use something like this:

```
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
id="file" mode="APPEND" charset="UTF-8"
directory="C:\\Users\\dvenkat1\\Desktop\\test" 
auto-create-directory="true"  filename-generator-expression="#xpath(payload, 'reference exp1 here']) " />

  <int-xml:xpath-expression id = "exp1"               
  expression="name(/soapNs:Envelope/soapNs:Body/schNs:processArchiveRequest/schNs: fulfillmentRequest/schNs:requestDetail/*[1])" 
namespace-map="archiveNamespaceMap" /> 

<util:map id="archiveNamespaceMap">
    <entry key="soapNs" value="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" />
    <entry key="schNs" value="http://blah../schema" />
</util:map>
```

Comment: This one is duplicated in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697148/how-to-reference-an-existing-xpath-expression

Comment: thanks @ArtemBilan.. I have deleted the other one and edited this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me like this:

```
filename-generator-expression="#xpath(payload, '//*[local-name()=&quot;requestID&quot;]')"
```

Pay attention to the escaped `"` symbol.

Regarding `<int-xml:xpath-expression>`.

You can use it from the the `filename-generator-expression` as well, but you should follow with the `XPathExpression` and therefore use `XmlPayloadConverter` manually. And do that everything somewhere from the custom bean.

Comment: this works thx.. A follow up question - I need to concatenate this xpath result with a value in a property file. how would I do that?

Comment: `#xpath(payload, '//*[local-name()=&quot;requestID&quot;]') + '${my.property}'`